# How to call worksheet function from word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, worksheet-function

I am trying to find maximum of a column in excel from word, previous i have used

```
MyResult = application.Worksheetfunction.max (Range("B4:B7"))
```

from excel, now i need to do similiar from vba in word.

But I can not figure out how to do this from word, do i need to make my own for loop and create my own max function?

```
maxVal =0
for i=2 to lastrow
    if xlapp.ws.cells(i,2)>maxVal then
      maxVal= xlapp.ws.cells(i,2)
    end if
 next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the my code based on input from AnlaystCave:

```
val(oXLApp.Worksheetfunction.Max( _
                xlApp.Sheets("List").Range(xlApp.Sheets("List").Cells(3, columnWp), xlApp.Sheets("List").Cells(numofrows, columnWp))))
```

Answer (score 1):

**I will first answer the question you posed:**

> How to call worksheet function from word

Like so:

```
 Dim excelApp As Object
 Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 maxVal = excelApp.Worksheetfunction.max(1, 2, 3) 'Some values separated by comma or an array
 excelApp.Quit
```

**Now what you need is just the Max function. Like so:**

```
Function MaxFunc(arr)
    Dim maxVal, tmpVal, ifFirst
    ifFirst = True
    For Each it In arr
        If ifFirst Then
            maxVal = it: ifFirst = False
        Else
            If maxVal < it Then maxVal = it
        End If
    Next
    MaxFunc = maxVal
End Function
```